# What are the left invariant Riemannian metrics on $SU(2)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand the concept of left-invariant Riemannian metrics on Lie groups. I know that for a Lie group G, the metric $g\in \Omega_{2}^{\text{sym}}(T(SU(2))^*)$ is *left invariant* if for any $h\in G$ the *left multiplication* map $L_h: G\to G$  defined by $L_h(s)=h\cdot s$ where $(\cdot)$ denotes the group operation on $G$ is a Riemannian Isometry such that for all $p\in G$ and $v,w\in T_p(G)$ we have:
$$g_p(v,w)= g_{L_h(p)}(D_pL_h(v),D_pL_h(w)) $$
It turns out that for this to hold, it suffices to say it is true for $p=e$ or the identity element on $G$.

To get a better grip on this definition I wanted to see an example. Take $SU(2)\subseteq  GL(2,\mathbb C)$ such that we can define a diffeomorphism $\phi: (\mathbb C^2)^{\times}\to SU(2) $ by:$$\phi(z,w)= \dfrac{1}{\lvert z\lvert^2+\lvert w\lvert^2}\begin{bmatrix} z & w \\
-\bar w &\bar z
\end{bmatrix} $$ The tangent space to SU(2) can be computed using this map at the identity $(1,0)= \phi^{-1}(e)$ such that $$T_e(SU(2))\cong \{e\} \times \begin{bmatrix} i\alpha & \beta+i\gamma\\  \beta-i\gamma &-i\alpha\end{bmatrix} \text{ for } (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in \mathbb R^3$$
This is isomorphic to a 3-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$. To put this in the language of differential forms we can consider $DL_h$ as an element of Aut$(T_e(SU(2))$ (since the tangent space of a Lie Group is isomorphic at all points). We are now simply after the family $\mathcal F\subset \Omega_{2}^{\text{sym}}(T(SU(2))^*)$ for which $ \omega \in F$ satisfies $(DL_h) ^{*}\omega= \omega$ for all $h\in G$.

I'm stuck on how to determine this family. It seems like this equation should translate to some system of differential equations. I'd welcome any suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: Fix any inner product $g_e$ on $T_e SU(2)$. Then, by definition, the left-invariant metric $g$ that extends it satisfies $L_h^* g = g$ for all $h$ and in particular $g_h = L_{h^{-1}}^* g_e$ for all $h$.